# How to override update path to patch instead of put in activerresource rails?

Tags: ruby, activeresource, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am using activeresource model, I need to consume API which supports only patch request method call for updating resource. How to override the update call in Active resource model?
Please advise

Comment: Can you show what you did so far?

Comment: @tversteeg: Added following method in Model  
  'def update
    connection.patch(element_path(prefix_options), encode, self.class.headers).tap do |response|
      load_attributes_from_response(response)
    end
  end'

Comment: This question has nothing to do with ActiveRestClient...

Comment: @AndyJeffries Indeed it was related to ActiveRESTClient. Suggested solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself.

Following code did the trick. Sent those parameters which are supposed to be updated only. Removed all other parameters from request.

```
  def update
    data = JSON.parse(encode)
    data_to_send = data.select{|k,v| ["name", "surname"].include?(k)}
    run_callbacks :update do
      connection.patch(element_path(prefix_options), data_to_send.to_json, self.class.headers).tap do |response|
        load_attributes_from_response(response)
      end
    end
  end
```